# Return local character array from a function

Tags: c++, c, string, visual-c++, pointers

How to return a local character array from one function

```
char* testfunction()
{
char array[] = "Hello World";
 return array;
}

char main()
{
 char* array = testfunction();
 printf(" %s -> string", array);
 return 0;
}
```

THis code results unknown error

�@$�@<��Ʉ؅�;���Y@��� -> string

Comment: Return a `std::string` instead.

Comment: `array` of size `3` cannot entirely hold "Hello World"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not return the address of the stack variable directly as it is destroyed once the stack frame is removed(after the function returns).

You could do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

char* testfunction()
{
   char *array = new char[32];
   std::fill(array, array + 32, 0); 
   snprintf(array, 32, "Hello World");
   return array;
}

int main()
{
   char* array = testfunction();
   printf(" %s -> string", array);
   delete[] array;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you now say what he should do isntead it would even be an answer ;)

Comment: Chance tehre to distroy the memory,

Comment: Unless you enjoy debugging memory leaks, return `std::string` (or some other [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) object) rather than hoping the caller knows what to do with a dumb pointer.

Comment: @MikeSeymour You're right, but since the question was about returning an array from a function, I gave this solution.

Answer (score 7):

You are returning a pointer which points to a local variable, when `testfunction()` returns `array` in main() becomes dangling pointer.

use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string testfunction()
{
    std::string str("Hello World");
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << testfunction() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this is what you want:

```
const char *testfunction(void)
{
        return "Hello World";
}
```

Comment: There is an assumption that OP doesn't want to modify `array`

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the address of a local variable. (if you use gcc you should get some warnings)

You can try to use the keyword `static` instead:

```
char    *test()
{
  static char array[] = "hello world";
  return (array);
}
```

Comment: This will cause interesting bugs when someone modifies it, and future calls return the modified value. (And if it's not meant to be modified, there's no point in the array at all - just return a `const` pointer to the literal).

Comment: well we don't know what the op want to do with it.
Hoover in the op code we can see only c and not c++.

But can you explain why you can get bugs ?

Comment: As I said: if anyone modifies the array returned by this function, then future calls will return the modified value. The code in the question tries (but fails) to return the same value each time; your code behaves in a surprisingly different way to that. (I suppose you could modify your version to rewrite the value each time; then you've just got reentrancy and thread-safety to worry about).

Comment: I guess my comprehension of English is not good enough and I haven't understood that the op tries to return the same value each time 
(How to return a local character array from one function)
Furthermore he declare a `char*` and not a `const char*`
Anyway it's a duplicate. (For someone who doesn't look at the warnings/errors of the compiler)